# How to train Tesseract on multiple files at once?

Tags: command-line, tesseract

When I first trained Tesseract the tutorial I used showed a way to run the commands on each relevant file, but I can no longer find that.

How could I run this command for each file:

```
tesseract [lang].[fontname].exp[num].tif [lang].[fontname].exp[num] batch.nochop makebox
```

Answer (score 1):

For a quick and dirty loop, you can try:

```
for i in *.tif ; do tesseract $i $i.txt; done;
```

You can also do it with a `find -iname ____ path` to select from a subset of files.

If you want to really "parse" filenames, you may want to use a scripting language, or get your bash-foo out.

Comment: note that tesseract automatically appends a .txt to the output file name, so having $i.txt would result in a $i.txt.txt output file.