# Tesseract: Advantage to Multi-Page Training File vs. Multiple Separate Files?

Tags: tesseract

This SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38004617/3541976) suggests that training tesseract with `.tif` files has an advantage over `.png` files because the `.tif` files can have multiple pages and thus a larger training sample.  Yet, this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22117441/how-to-train-tesseract-on-multiple-files-at-once) discusses procedures for training with multiple images at once.  More so, the `man` page for, e.g. `mftraining` suggests that it can accept multiple training files.

Is there any reason then not to train with multiple separate image files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that using multiple images to train tesseract on a single font seems to work just fine.  Below is a sketch of the workflow I employ:

```
# Convert files to .pdf
convert -density 600 Page1.pdf eng1.MyNewFont.exp1.png
convert -density 600 Page2.pdf eng1.MyNewFont.exp2.png

# Create .box files
tesseract eng1.MyNewFont.exp1.png eng1.MyNewFont.exp1 -l eng batch.nochop makebox
tesseract eng1.MyNewFont.exp2.png eng1.MyNewFont.exp2 -l eng batch.nochop makebox

## correct boxes with jTessBoxEditor or another box editor ##

# Create two new box.tr files: eng1.MyNewFont.exp1.box.tr and eng1.MyNewFont.exp2.box.tr

tesseract eng1.MyNewFont.exp1.png eng1.MyNewFont.exp1.box -l eng1 nobatch box.train.stderr
tesseract eng1.MyNewFont.exp2.png eng1.MyNewFont.exp2.box -l eng1 nobatch box.train.stderr

# Extract characters from the two .box files
unicharset_extractor eng1.MyNewFont.exp1.box eng1.MyNewFont.exp2.box 

echo "MyNewFont 0 0 0 0 0" >> font_properties

# train using the two new box.tr files.
mftraining -F font_properties -U unicharset -O eng1.unicharset eng1.MyNewFont.exp1.box.tr eng1.MyNewFont.exp2.box.tr 
cntraining eng1.MyNewFont.exp1.box.tr eng1.MyNewFont.exp2.box.tr

## rename files
mv inttemp  eng1.inttemp
mv normproto  eng1.normproto
mv pffmtable  eng1.pffmtable
mv shapetable  eng1.shapetable

combine_tessdata eng1. ## create .traineddata file.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly train with multiple image files; Tesseract would treat them as having different, separate fonts. And there is a limit (64) on the number of images. If they share a common font, it would be better to put them in a multi-page TIFF. According to its specs, a TIFF file can be a container holding many images.

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format

Comment: Will Tesseract necessarily treat them as different fonts?  I edited my question to give a workflow that I *think* uses two images to train a single font.  Is there something flawed about it though?  Thanks!

Comment: I normally train with multi-page TIFF, but your workflow seems to be workable, except it appears to miss a couple steps (commands).